# Logical AND/OR in Keras Backend

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Tensorflow has `tf.logical_and()` and `tf.logical_or()` for comparison of two boolean tensors, i.e. `tf.logical_and(x,y)==TRUE` if `x==TRUE and y==TRUE` [(doc)](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/logical_and%20doc).  I can't find anything like this in the Keras backend though.  They have `keras.backend.any()` and `.all()`, but this is for aggregation within a tensor, not between.  I've been having to use workarounds with nested `K.switch()` functions, but it is painfully inelegant.

Comment: You actually don't have to worry about this, because you can directly use `tf.logical_and` in a `keras` model just as you call `K.xxx`.

Comment: Only if you are using the tensorflow backend...

Comment: Yes. So you use a different backend?

Comment: Well no but I'm trying to make a Keras compatible library.. if you were just going to write for tensorflow you wouldn't need any of keras.backend

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let `x` and `y` be boolean keras tensors of the same shape.

To take elementwise or, do the following:

```
keras.backend.any(keras.backend.stack([x, y], axis=0), axis=0)
```

To take elementwise and, do the following:

```
keras.backend.all(keras.backend.stack([x, y], axis=0), axis=0)
```

Here `keras.backend.stack([x, y], axis=0)` stacks x and y into a new tensor with an additional dimension at number 0.  After that `keras.backend.any` takes a logical or along the new dimension, and `keras.backend.any` takes the logical and.

Answer (score 3):

My solution (perhaps not the best, because I haven't found others either), is:

```
A = K.cast(someBooleanTensor, K.floatx())
B = K.cast(anotherBooleanTensor, K.floatx())

A_and_B = A * B #this is also something I use a lot for gathering elements
A_or_B = 1 -((1-A)*(1-B))
```

But thinking about it now... I never tested python operators... perhaps they work?

Comment: Doesn't seem like you can use python logical operators - getting error `raise TypeError("Using a 'tf.Tensor' as a Python 'bool' is not allowed.`.

Comment: :( -- But the multiplication above is sure thing.